# How to insert thousands of records into db

Tags: spring, hibernate

I want to insert 10.000 records into db but it takes nearly 2 minutes. How can I increase insert speed? I am using batch-insert but I think it isn't increasing speed too much(3 or 4 seconds maybe). Is there any idea?

My save function;

```
for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
        getCurrentSession().save(userList.get(i));
        if (i % 50 == 0) {
            getCurrentSession().flush();
            getCurrentSession().clear();
        }
    }
```

Config;

```
<prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>
```

**Edit:** I am using PostgreSql and here is my table;

```
id character varying(50) NOT NULL,
name character varying(200) NOT NULL,
register_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
alias character varying(200),
title character varying(200),
type character varying(50),
CONSTRAINT pk_registered_user PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Comment: You will probably have a hard time speeding this up. Inserting 60 items per second is not fast, on the other hand it is not extremely slow either. You might need use different approach if you want to speed up (bulk loads, dropping constraints, ...). Have you tested how much is pure JDBC faster? You need to know what to tune up and better make sure that Hibernate is the bottleneck. What DB are you using?

Comment: Turn on debug logging and whatch what SQL statements are executed by Hibernate. It is possible that Hibernate tries to insert data into some other related tables. Also, any read during a batch insert negates any benefits of batching.

Comment: @Olaf There are only thousands of insert statements in logs. There is no other table in db.

Comment: @hellzone: How much freedom do you have to experiment with your database? I would've try to disable any foreign keys to the pk_registered_user and see if the inserts go faster. If they do, there's not much you can do about it other than tweaking the database schema or chosing another dbms. Also, from my experience with loading large amounts of data with Hibernate, a batch size of 200-500 performs best.